# Meta_query question

Tags: custom-post-types, search, meta-query

There is a problem with compiling a request to display posts by meta_query.
Need to output posts whose title contains a substring.
Can't figure out where I'm wrong. Can someone help?

```
$inputValue = 'Palm';
    echo $inputValue;
    $args = [
        'post_type' => 'projects',
        'order'  => 'DESC',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_status'=> 'publish',      
        'meta_query' => [ [
            'key' => 'title',
            'value' => 'Palm',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ] ],
    ];
   }  
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
      if (  $query->have_posts() ) { ?>
       <h2 class="portfolio__name">
         <a href="<? the_permalink() ?>"> <? the_title() ?></a>
       </h2>                      
   <?php endwhile;  wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Comment: The title isn't meta. `WP_Query` doesn't support querying by substring of the title (searching with the `s` argument is similar, but probably not what you want). You'll need to filter the SQL query itself with the [`posts_where`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_where/) hook.

Comment: Thanks for answer.